# MySQL multiple Join tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, multiple-tables

I have created the following tables:

```
Table: autor
id_autor   nom_aut    rfc_aut  pseudo_id
  A1     Juan Salinas
  A3       Quijote               A7
  A8       Sancho                A1
  A7        Luis     LISA98439
```

As you can see the table Autor has a recursive, reflexive relation.
The next table is:

```
Table: articulo
id_art   nom_art   num_pag_art
   1    Article 1      10
   2    Article 2      30
   3    Article 3      20
```

I want to show the following table but I cannot make it:

```
id_autor  nom_aut       nom_real  id_art  nom_art
   A1     Juan Salinas              1     Article 1
   A3      Quijote       Luis       3     Article 3
```

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT autor.id_autor as 'ID de Autor', 
autor.nom_aut as 'Nombre Autor',
autor.nom_aut  as 'Autor Real',
articulo.id_art as 'ID de Articulo',
articulo.nom_art as 'Nombre de Articulo'
FROM autor.nom_aut join articulo.id_art on autor.pseudo_id=autor.id_autor
left join autor.pseudo_id on autor.pseudo_id=autor_pseudo.id;
```

But I cannot make the table show the information I want.

MySQL shows:

```
Error Code: 1146. Table 'autor.nom_aut' doesn't exist
```

Any idea what kind of instructions do I have to use? 
Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the table with it self:

```
SELECT autor.id_autor as 'ID de Autor', 
autor.nom_autor as 'Nombre Autor',
autor_pseudo.nom_aut  as 'Autor Real',
articulo.id_art as 'ID de Articulo',
articulo.nom_art as 'Nombre de Articulo'
FROM autor autor join articulo articulo on autor.pseudo_id=autor.id_autor
left join autor autor_pseudo on autor.pseudo_id=autor_pseudo.id;
```

Comment: It shows an error after the ; where the left join is. Any idea why? Thanks btw!

Comment: @MichVellve yes sorry.

Comment: @MichVellve In your example you have wrote the name of the referenced record, not the id?!

Comment: You made a misstak by copiing the query: `left join autor.pseudo_id on autor.pseudo_id=autor_pseudo.id;` must be `left join autor autor_pseudo on autor.pseudo_id=autor_pseudo.id;`

Comment: @MichVellve And this line is also not in your query: `autor_pseudo.nom_aut  as 'Autor Real',`

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry but why do you put autor_pseudo? I don't see the table autor_pseudo from where you are taking that name in the query.
MySQL shows an error because of that: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'autor_pseudo.nom_aut' in 'field list'

Comment: If you join a table twice you have to put an alias on the tables so mysql know from which table you whant to see the column. I hope this heps for understanding. Can you show the statement you actualy have?